# Running i386 and applications using Rosetta on M1

Tags: big-sur, apple-silicon, rosetta

I'm trying to run Wine on my M1 Macbook. I can get wine64 working, but because my programs have some x86 bits, it also needs wine. However, trying to run it says `zsh: bad CPU type in executable: bin/wine`. I could try QEMU user-mode, but that requires you to have the loader and the libraries, both are not easy to get. So, is there any way to run i386 applications with Apple's M1 Mac?